# Not getting any sound on ubuntu studio

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio

I use an audio interface while recording my guitar. But, i am not getting any sound on anything if i use my laptop without the interface. 
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type "alsamixer" in console and use F6 to select your card. Check your outputs, up/down arrows to change volume.

Comment: It worked, thank you!!!